# Google Maps Engine - Importing Google Maps "My Maps" Data

Tags: google-maps, csv, kml, xlsx

I have a number of maps in the original Google Maps "My Maps" which I have been maintaining for some time now.  I noticed that Google now has Google Maps Engine which appears to be a bit more powerful and would allow me to combine all my maps into a single map with multiple layers.

However, I would rather not remake all of my maps in this new system.  I attempted to export/import the data from My Maps to the Engine using KML, but Engine will not accept KML for import.  Likewise, My Maps does not appear to export to CSV or XLSX, the formats which Engine will accept.

Is there some method to export maps from "My Maps" and import them into Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it seems like the google maps engine does indeed give you option of importing the maps you saved in your 'My Maps' as layers on to your map. Have a look at the screencap below:
[image]

It has the option of uploading your csv or xlsx files, but there's also the option right under to add the maps you saved in "My Maps". I assume you'll need to be logged into your Google account with the saved maps to access this though.

Comment: Why thank you for that entirely elegant answer...geez, I'm blind.